# Como fazer para uma DIV ocupar o espaço correto?

Tags: html, css, angular, div

Boa noite, estou montando o layout de um projeto de aprendizado meu, preciso fazer com que a div ocupe o espaço igual a imagem azul abaixo
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O meu código é o seguinte:

Meu HTML e meu CSS estão abaixo:

```css
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto';
.left-menu {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 300px;
  list-style-type: none;
  background: #f32c52;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: width .5s;
}

.left-menu:hover {
  width: 300px;
}

.left-menu li {
  width: 300px;
}

.left-menu li span {
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin: 20px 30px 0 22px;
}

.left-menu li a {
  display: block;
  font-size: .9rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFF;
  height: 60px;
}

.left-menu li a:hover {
  background: #ffff;
}


.left-menu li:first-child a {
  background: #14081d;
  display: block;
  height: 150px;
}

.up-menu {
  background:#14081d;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  color: white;
  text-align: right;
}

.content {
  border: solid 1px green;
  color: green;
  margin-top: 56px;  
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
 href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />


<ul class="left-menu">  
  <li>
      <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-code"></span>Imagem</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-cog"></span>Menu1</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-font"></span>Menu2</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div class="up-menu">
  up-menu
</div>

<div class="content">
  div-content
</div>
```

Não consigo fazer com o que a minha "div-content" fique como o desenho que fiz com o quadrado azul pois nenhum tipo de margem ou tamanho que aplique na div content funciona :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisaria utilizar o `calc` para ajustar as dimensões da div, descontando a largura da coluna lateral no `width` e a altura da barra superior no `height`, mas é preciso também ajustar a altura do `html, body` em `100%` e retirar o margin natural do `body`. Logo, acrescente no seu CSS:

```
html, body{
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0;
}
```

E altere o `width` e o `height` da `div.content`, acrescentando também um `margin-left` para que a div não fique por baixo da coluna, que é fixa:

```
.content {
  border: solid 1px green;
  color: green;
  margin-top: 60px;
  margin-left: 310px;
  width: calc(100% - 320px);
  height: calc(100% - 70px);
}
```

Assim a div terá um espaçamento externo de `10px` (que você ajustar alterando os valores `320px` e `70px`.

Veja:

```css
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto';

html, body{
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0;
}

.left-menu {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 300px;
  list-style-type: none;
  background: #f32c52;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: width .5s;
}

.left-menu:hover {
  width: 300px;
}

.left-menu li {
  width: 300px;
}

.left-menu li span {
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin: 20px 30px 0 22px;
}

.left-menu li a {
  display: block;
  font-size: .9rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFF;
  height: 60px;
}

.left-menu li a:hover {
  background: #ffff;
}


.left-menu li:first-child a {
  background: #14081d;
  display: block;
  height: 150px;
}

.up-menu {
  background:#14081d;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  color: white;
  text-align: right;
}

.content {
  border: solid 1px green;
  color: green;
  margin-top: 60px;
  margin-left: 310px;
  width: calc(100% - 320px);
  height: calc(100% - 70px);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<ul class="left-menu">  
  <li>
      <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-code"></span>Imagem</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-cog"></span>Menu1</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-font"></span>Menu2</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div class="up-menu">
  up-menu
</div>

<div class="content">
  div-content
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado sam!
Esses posts com explicações são essenciais pra quem ta iniciando.

Comment: Estranho que no seu exemplo funciona, o meu no ctrl c + ctrl v não funciona

Comment: Então talvez deve ser outra coisa no CSS

Comment: tem relação ao uso de bootstrap ???

Comment: Sim, com certeza. O Bootstrap tem sistema de grid próprio.

Comment: Existe algo que eu possa fazer pra eliminar o bootstrap e aplicar o css?

Comment: Ué, é só não usar o bootstrap.

Comment: O problema é que perderia todos os meus outros estilos nas outras páginas kk

Comment: É só não carregar o bootstrap apenas nessa página.